# How to transfer data from a controller to a socket.io in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm building an web app to receive data from an api using nodejs as backend, and show this data on the client side using React. But it's my first time using socket.io.

**Sockets.ts**

```
function socket( io ){
    io.on("connection", socket => {
        var socketId = socket.id;
        var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
        console.log('New connection ' + socketId + ' from ' + clientIp);
        
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
          console.log("Client disconnected");
        });
      
      });
}

export default socket;
```

**router.controller.ts**

```
export const getData: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {

  
  const options= {
    method: 'GET',
  };

  const response = await fetch(citybikeurl, options)
    .then((res: any) => res.json())  
    .catch((e: any) => {
      console.error({ error: e });
    });
  
  
  console.log("RESPONSE: ", response);
  res.json(response);
  
}
```

**routes.ts**

```
router.get('/', dataController.getData)
```

At the moment, I don't know if I'm passing any data from controller.ts to Sockets.ts, and after of this be able to emit the results.

Comment: pass express `app` instance to the socket, then put the socket.io connection in `app.set('io', io)` etc then in the controller you can do `req.app.get('io').emit('etc')`, or init the connection outside socket() func in your code and just return the connection, lots of ways you could even use a custom EventEmitter, personally I like to use a class for routes and have a sockets(){} method in the class, which on boot it injects it into the events, this way all routes/socket events for say user are where they should be

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying exactly as you explain me,  but I obtain the next error: (node:27834) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: req.app.get(...).emit is not a function. The actual code is   `req.app.get('io').emit(response)` in the controller, and `app.set('io', io)` in the app.ts

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a socket on the server-side as well.
Please refer to this guide for how to set up a socket server:
https://medium.com/@raj_36650/integrate-socket-io-with-node-js-express-2292ca13d891

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. The code that I published is from the server side. Im going to check your recommendation. PSDT. Just now I have connected the client side and the server side as well, But it only send me the console messages that is in the socket code.